# Make OpenVPN accessible from outside the network

Tags: remote, openvpn

I'm trying to get openvpn working on my centos machine but I'm having some issues
and I don't really know much about openvpn.

I've managed to get it working and I can connect to it with another machine while on the same network but what will I have to do to be able to connect from outside the network?

The Centos machine has a static IP address 10.0.0.66 and when I try to forward the port 1194 it says that it is closed no matter what I do (iptables is disabled completely for testing)

I know there's nothing wrong with the port forwarding because I have an apache web server running on the same machine (which has now been removed so as not to interfere with testing) and that port is working fine

I have included the following settings

server.conf

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

user nobody
group nobody
```

sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

firewall

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```